# Algebraic independence of some exponential values

Tags: nt.number-theory

Good morning,

I try to prove the following conjecture. Let $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ be $n$ algebraic numbers such that $(1,\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\left(e^{i\pi \alpha_1},\dots,e^{i\pi \alpha_n}\right)$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

The statement is very close to the Lindemann Weiertrass Theorem except for the $i\pi$ factor. So I tried to follow the proof but still very fast a problem appears because $e^{i\pi \alpha}$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}$ are algebraic. The case $n=1$ can be solved using the Gelfand Theorem which implies that $e^{i\pi \alpha}$ with $\alpha\in\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is transcendental. The general case is also a subcase of the Schanuel conjecture, but this never uses the specific form of the arguments in the exponentials.

Remark that the converse of the conjecture is easy, as if $(1,\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ are dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$, a simple product of the exponentials with integer powers equals to $1$. I thank anyone that could give me an idea or a reference.

Comment: If the conclusion is algebraic independence, then this is very close to Schanuel and likely hopeless.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Why hopeless ? has it been proved undecidable ? if not, one should state, leaving the hope open, "it seems out of reach, so far".